# Date token to use user timezone instead of site timezone

Tags: tokens, datetime

Our site is having users from different timezones and we are sending event notification emails using rules. We need to specify the event date-time in addressee's timezone.

So, is there any way to specify the the timezone within/along with date-time token?

Or, should I introduce a custom token for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can try date token with custom date formatting

```
[entity:field-event-date:custom:m/d/y T]
```

replace `entity` with appropriate token (`node`, etc.), and insert the name of your date field.

Refer to [PHP:date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for custom date formats.

Comment: It will display it in default timezone, here I want to pass my different timezone to token.